# Is it possible get a Visual Graph representation of a List Object in R?

Tags: r, igraph

Is it possible get a Visual Graph representation of a List Object in R ?

For example:

```
a <- list("a", "b", TRUE, 3.14, 0-5i, -2:3, c("Hello", "World"), 
                                                    list("π", "∑ µ", "ß"))
plot(a)
```

This code returns an error

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>       'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Comment: What did you expect would happen when you ran `plot(a)` ?

Comment: I expect visualize the dependence graph (Object Oriented vision) between objects (DAG visual construction). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, the [listviewer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/listviewer/index.html) package will accomplish the visual representation you expect.

```
library(listviewer)
a <- list("a", "b", TRUE, 3.14, 0-5i, -2:3, c("Hello", "World"), 
                                                list("π", "∑ µ", "ß"))
jsonedit(a)
```